# How to parse PDF documents using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to extract a text using a rectangle's coordinates in itextsharp. I have tried solving my problem using this code.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
            var pageHeight = reader.GetPageSize(1).Height;
            var pageWidth = reader.GetPageSize(1).Width;
            var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(x1,y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);
            RenderFilter[] renderFilter = new RenderFilter[1];
            renderFilter[0] = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
            ITextExtractionStrategy textExtractionStrategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), renderFilter);
            return PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, textExtractionStrategy);
```

but couldn't able to extract the value I want. I have obtained the rectangle location by allowing the user to draw on the converted image of the pdf document which is loaded on canvas element.

Sorry about my English.

Comment: What errors or failures do you run into? Any more informations to help us helping you?

Comment: The question is unclear as the desired result, nor the actual result are shared with us. We'd also need access to the PDF document to examine the way the content is stored. For instance: if it's a scanned image, nothing will be returned. If the font is stored incorrectly, only gibberish will be returned. We can't tell what goes wrong without more information.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for your quick response. The desired result is that I want to overwrite the content of the pdf at a specific location marked as a rectangle by the user. The error I am facing is that I have tried to transform the coordinates starting position from the upper left corner to bottom left corner but couldn't able to get the text at the specified location.one thing to add the pdf is not a scanned image it's created using itext

Comment: *couldn't able to get the text at the specified location* - but **what did you get**? Text from a completely different position? Too much or too little text from approximately the right position? Nothing?

Comment: I have got a text from a different position and sometimes it only returns an empty string.